# Is this a linear functional on $H^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Let $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $f \in L^2(a,b)$ and define the map: $\varphi:H^1(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}; v \mapsto \int_a^b f(x) \cdot v(x) ~dx$.
Is $\varphi$ now a functional on $H^1(a,b)$?
Clearly it is linear but I don't see why it should be continous.
 I would need to find $L>0$ with $\mid \int_a^b f(x) \cdot v(x) ~dx \mid \leq L \left\lVert v \right\rVert_{H^1} $ but I don't see an obvious candidate.

Comment: Can’t we just use Cauchy-Schwarz and take $L= \| f \|_{L^2}$ since $\| v \|_{L^2} \le \| v\|_{H^1}$?

Comment: @User8128 you're right, I guess you did find an obvious candidate. Not sure how I could miss that